# Erro 1452 mysql: erro na chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql

eu criei duas tabelas de produto a `tbl_produto` e a `tbl_adiciona`, assim ao invés de toda vez que eu quiser atualizar o estoque, eu não tenha dois dados iguais na tabela de produtos, e sim em uma tabela exterior.

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->  
create table tbl_produto(
cod_produto int not null primary key,
nome_produto varchar(50) not null, 
quantidade int not null
);

create table tbl_adiciona(
cod_adiciona int not null primary key auto_increment,
cod_produto int not null,
nome_produto varchar(50),
quantidade int not null
);

alter table tbl_adiciona add constraint fk_codProduto foreign key(cod_produto)   
references tbl_produto (cod_produto);
```

Pois bem, para isso eu criei 2 funções e 1 trigger para ajudar nesse processo.

```
delimiter %

CREATE FUNCTION valor()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    declare ultimoAdc int;
    set ultimoAdc = (select a.cod_produto from tbl_adiciona a where a.cod_adiciona = 
(select max(cod_adiciona) from tbl_adiciona));
    return ultimoAdc;
END%

delimiter $$ 

CREATE FUNCTION adicionaValor(cod int) 
RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    declare valorAtual int;
    declare valorAntigo int;
    select quantidade from tbl_produto where cod_produto = cod into valorAtual;
    select quantidade from tbl_adiciona where cod_produto = cod and cod_adiciona = 
    ( select cod_adiciona from tbl_adiciona where cod_produto = cod order by 
cod_adiciona DESC LIMIT 1) into
        valorAntigo;
    set @valorTot = valorAtual + valorAntigo;
    return @valorTot;
END$$

delimiter ?

create trigger trg_adiciona AFTER INSERT ON tbl_adiciona    
for each row
BEGIN
    declare cod int; 
    set cod = valor();

    if exists(select cod_produto from tbl_produto where cod_produto = cod) then 
        update tbl_produto set quantidade = adicionaValor(cod) where cod_produto = cod;
    else
        insert into tbl_produto(cod_produto,nome_produto,quantidade) 
        value
        (
          (select cod_produto from tbl_adiciona a where a.cod_produto = cod),
          (select nome_produto from tbl_adiciona a where a.cod_produto = cod),
          (select quantidade from tbl_adiciona a where a.cod_produto = cod)
        );
    end if;

END?
```

O código funciona, até o `ELSE`. Fiz esse bloco de código para caso eu adicionasse um registro não existente na tabela de produtos, ele inserisse automaticamente na tabela e fizesse com que os próximos registros com o mesmo código seja atualizado na tabela de produtos, não havendo 2 produtos iguais na mesma tabela (exceto a `tbl_adiciona`, ja que ela serve de log).

o log do problema é :

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
 (`teste`.`tbl_adiciona`, CONSTRAINT `fk_codProduto` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_produto`) REFERENCES
 `tbl_produto` (`cod_produto`))
```

Como resolvo esse problema?

EDIT : Dados inseridos na tabela para teste :

```
insert into tbl_produto(cod_produto,nome_produto,quantidade) values
(1,'Achocolatado',10),
(2,'Maionese',20),
(3,'Leite condensado',30);

insert into tbl_adiciona (cod_produto,nome_produto,quantidade) values
(1,'Achocolatado',20),
(2,'Maionese',10);
```

Comment: Já tem dados em alguma das tabelas?

Comment: Sim! acabei de inserir eles no tópico

Comment: Os campos correntes da operação devem ser tratados por .old e .new    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Boa, valeu! Ajudou bastante no que eu já tinha pesquisado